# Android Spinner Dynamic value using for Loop

Tags: android, android-spinner

I would like to have a spinner with a dynamic value for month from 1-12, day 1-31, and for the year from 1917 to Current year.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_Month"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_Day"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_Year"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


    List year = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1917; i <= "IwantThisTobeInCurrentYear - 18"; i++) {
        year.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, year);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.years_spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

and inside the for loop I want This To be In Current Year - 18 to Avoid Less than 18.
and I want to set the default value to YEAR or YYYY

Comment: please show full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) instead.

**1.** Create `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //Change date format if required
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);

        String dateStr = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

        EditText editText = null; //initialize edit text here
        editText.setText(dateStr);
        //use this date
    }

};
```

**2.** Show date picker on button click etc

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =new DatePickerDialog(context, datePickerListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you teach/guide me how to use a DatePicker? when I touch the EditText the Datepicker will pop out then the selected date will be at the EditText?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: okie2x I get it. thnx.. hehe context to this. problem solve thnx